# Is it possible that SqlException is thrown and property Number == 0?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlexception

Is it possible that SqlException will be thrown when trying to execute sql procedure and property Number will be 0?

Specific situation: domain controller is not available/not responding and no real communication with sql server occurred.

Comment: check this:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: and this :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you mean interrupted connectivity when a SqlConnection has already been opened before? The client components would in this case still throw an "A transport-level error has occurred..." message, an that exception does have a number (19 - Physical connection is not usable). There *are* defined error states with number == 0 though.

Comment: By domain controller you mean the application/URL is down?

Comment: Not only is this possible, there are entire classes of `SqlException` instances that get thrown without SQL Server ever being involved, and it's not even particularly easy to know when this has happened. Error numbers are not consistently assigned; sometimes you get an SQL error number, sometimes a Win32 error number.

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Active Directory domain controller was not working - i don`t have all the details except that disk was full.

Comment: @dlatikay I suspect that it could have happen when trying to open connection.

Answer (score 1):

No, it should not be possible that `SqlException.Number` is 0, except for the following cases:

- Read-only routing failure
- Server had severe error processing query
- Processed cancellation while parsing results
- Failed to create user instance

Assuming you're not using read-only routing of SQL Server 2016, then none of these cases could apply to the scenario you described.

Remaining cases are either a non-zero number from `sysmessages`, or a Win32 error code (which, since 0 == `ERROR_SUCCESS`, would also never be zero).

In practice you will see something along the lines of "Cannot create SSPI context", or "A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server", or a "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host", and those have nonzero Win32 error codes too.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number(v=vs.110).aspx

It may be worth noting that `SqlException.Number` is synonym for the `Number` property of the first entry in its `Errors` array, and that array might contain more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. Yes, it is possible. We added aditional code to catch:

```
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
    {
        this.logger.Error("Index #" + i + "\n" +
        "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
        "Error Number: " + ex.Errors[i].Number + "\n" +
        "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
        "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
        "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
    }                       

    if (ex.Number == 0)
    {
        this.logger.Warn("Exception was caught but ex.Number == 0! Changing to -69.");
        oResults.Add("_ExitCode", "-69");
    }
}
```

and this was logged today.

```
2017-01-17 08:05:08,282 [r074008903] ERROR ProcessLogger Index #0
Message: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Error Number: 0
LineNumber: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure: 

2017-01-17 08:05:08,282 [r074008903] ERROR ProcessLogger Index #1
Message: A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Error Number: 0
LineNumber: 0
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Procedure: 

2017-01-17 08:05:08,283 [r074008903] WARN  ProcessLogger Exception was caught but ex.Number == 0! Changing to -69.
```

Because in other place _ExitCode was used to determine is something was wrong in this specific situation we had false information.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

I receive 0 when trying to connect SQL which is starting inside ubuntu container. According to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15 
that is undocumented and, probably, is a bug.

Here is my situation, for example:
[image]